# Why is jquery remote validation working although I have not included the libraries

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-dialog, jquery-validate

Why is jquery remote/validation working in my dialog although I have not included those libraries in my index View opening the dialog?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Look at the page's HTML source in the browser.

Comment: yes its there because its included in the Layout file. But often I see or have read I should include those files where I use validation etc.So should I never include those files in other sites then the main site where the html,document starts?

Comment: Why do partials views get jquery validation references included when I create a new partial view in visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess: you are using ASP.NET MVC 4 and in the head section of your `_Layout` there's a script Bundle inclusion which automatically includes all the javascript files in the Scripts folder. So while you have not explicitly included those scripts, they are there. The unobtrusive validation cannot possibly work without them.